# Writing to a txt file using GetSaveFileName

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am trying to use the GetSaveFileName to store a number of strings in a txt file. The function makes use of the struct OpenFileName. I have looked thoroughly at the members of the struct under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but I still cannot figure out which member is responsible for the content of the file. In other words how can I pass the text to the txt. file opened? Or can this not be done at once, hence I should use another function subsequently?

Comment: The function is called `GetSaveFileName`, not `GetSaveFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is only to create the "Save as..." dialog box and retrieving the file name the user chose, not for actually saving the file; after it returned, you can retrieve the selected file name from `lpstrFile` and use it however you want (you will probably use `ofstream` to write to it).